# don't show batch file command when execute it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

when i execute batch file on cmd screen the command in the batch appear on the screen example :-

batch file :-
`@echo off.
command1
command2`

when i execute it on cmd the following appear on screen :-
`c:\user > command1
 c:\user >command2`

i dont to appear anything when i execute batch file

Comment: Remove the dot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you want to separate commands on individual lines...

```
@echo off
command1
command2
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 10):

Mmmmm....`@echo off` is what turns off the command echoing.  If you want to see your batch file list off your commands as it runs them, don't use `@echo off` at the start of your script.  Also, the `@` sign at the start of the line makes just that line not echo.  So you could use that to selectively hide the commands you didn't want to see.


--Christopher Karel